# Convert $f(x)=(\cos(x))^3$ to powers of x and find if converges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I started out by writing the Taylor series for $x_0=0$ (Maclaurin series) of $f(x)=(\cos(x))^3$.

If my calculations are correct $$f(x)=1-\frac{3x^2}{2!}+\frac{21x^4}{4!}-\frac{183x^2}{6!}+...$$
and after some simplifications $$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}a_n$$ where $a_n$ is a sequence of $a_0=1, a_1=3, a_2=21,a_3=183, ..$

Is there any way to find the $a_n$ sequence or a better way to solve the whole problem?

Comment: Note that, at least formally, $f(x) = \left(1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \cdots\right)^3$.

Comment: The way I would compute it is to use the half-angle formula and change $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\cos x(1+\cos2x)$. That way you only have to compute one product of series, and the pattern for $a_n$ might be easier to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the identity $\cos(3x)=4\cos^3 x-3\cos x$ it follows

\begin{align}
\cos^3x&=\frac{1}{4}\cos (3x)+\frac{3}{4}\cos x\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{(3x)^{2k}}{(2k)!}+\frac{3}{4}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{(x)^{2k}}{(2k)!}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{3(3^{2k-1}+1)}{(2k)!}x^{2k}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. One may recall that
$$
\cos^3 x=\frac14 \cos (3x)+\frac34\cos x
$$ then use
$$
\cos x=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n}, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\cos^3x=\frac{1}{4}(3\cos(x)+\cos(3x))$. But

$\cos(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{(2k)!}$

$\cos(3x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-9)^kx^{2k}}{(2k)!}$

Then

$\begin{eqnarray}
4\cos^3(x)&=&3\cos(x)+\cos(3x)\\
&=&3\sum_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{(2k)!}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-9)^kx^{2k}}{(2k)!}\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{[3(-1)^k+(-9)^k]x^{2k}}{(2k)!}\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{a_kx^{2k}}{(2k)!}
\end{eqnarray}$

where $a_0=4$ and $a_{n+1}=-10a_n-9a_{n-1}$.